# Query Graphql return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

i doing a project with Graphql and the React but i have a problem, a query is returning value `undefined`. I'm passing the values to variables, all right but is giving that...

My Query that return `undefined` (with React) (FilterResult):

```js
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';
import { InlineLoading } from 'carbon-components-react';
import ReactSVG from 'react-svg';

import Module from '../../components/Module/Module';
import ViewMore from '../../components/ViewMore/ViewMore';

import SearchContext from './context';
import { GET_POSITIONS_BY_FILTER } from './queries';
import Position from '../../components/Position/Position';
import { HorizontalSeparator } from '../dashboard/styled';
import emptySearchIcon from './empty-search.svg';
import { EmptySearchContainer, ViewMoreContainer } from './styled.js';

const FilterResult = () => (
  <SearchContext.Consumer>
    {context => (
      <Query query={GET_POSITIONS_BY_FILTER} variables={{ filters: context.filters, offset: 0 }}>
        {({ data, loading, fetchMore }) => {
          if (loading) return <InlineLoading description="Loading..." />;

          let filterResult;
          {
            data.filter.positions.length
              ? (filterResult = (
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', width: '100%' }}>
                  {data.filter.positions.map((position, index, arr) => (
                    <Fragment key={position.id}>
                      <Position position={position} />
                      {index + 1 !== arr.length ? <HorizontalSeparator /> : null}
                    </Fragment>
                  ))}
                </div>
              ))
              : (filterResult = (
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', width: '100%' }}>
                  <EmptySearchContainer>
                    <ReactSVG path={emptySearchIcon} />
                    <h5>No results found</h5>
                    <h6>Try different filters or keywords and search it again</h6>
                  </EmptySearchContainer>
                </div>
              ));
          }

          return (
            <React.Fragment>
              <Module title="All Results" description={` - ${data.filter.positions.length} job opportunities`}>
                {filterResult}
              </Module>
              <ViewMoreContainer>
                <a onClick={() => fetchMore({
                  variables: {
                    offset: data.filter.positions.length
                  },
                  updateQuery: (prev, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
                    if (!fetchMoreResult) return prev;
                    return {
                      ...prev,
                      filter: {
                        ...prev.filter,
                        positions: [
                          ...prev.filter.positions,
                          ...fetchMoreResult.filter.positions
                        ]
                      }
                    };
                  }
                })}>View More</a>
              </ViewMoreContainer>

            </React.Fragment>

          );
        }}
      </Query>
    )}

  </SearchContext.Consumer>
);

export default FilterResult;
```

The variable `undefined` is the `data`.

My typedef:

```js
const Position = `
  input InputFilters {
    status: [String!]
    country: String
    city: String
    band: Int
    role: String
    businessUnit: String
    domain: String,
    subDomain: String,
    keywords: String,
  }
  
  type PositionFilters {
    countries: [String!]
    cities(country: String!): [String!]
    roles: [String!]
    businessUnit: [String!]
    domains: [String!]
    subDomains(domain: String!): [String!]
    positions(filters: InputFilters!, offset: Int): [Position!]
  }
  
  type Position {
    id: ID!
    type: PositionType!
    role: String!
    responsibilities: String
    skills: String
    country: String!
    quantity: Int
    expirationDate: Timestamp!
    availableDate: Timestamp!
    band: Int!
    functionalManager: String!
    bluepagesManager: String!
    managementContact: String!
    gomNumber: String
    location: String!
    businessUnit: String!
    domain: String!
    subDomain: String!
    viewCount: Int
    favoriteCount: Int
    owner_id: String!
    closed: Boolean
    closedType: ClosedType
    owner: User!
    favorites: [User!]!
    views: [User!]!
    created_at: Timestamp!
    updated_at: Timestamp!
  }
  
 `;

module.exports = Position;
```

My `resolver`:

```js
const Position = require('./position.model');
const User = require('../User/user.model');
const Favorite = require('../Favorite/favorite.model');
const View = require('../View/view.model');

const { AuthenticationError } = require('apollo-server-express');

module.exports = {
  Query: {
    positions() {
      return Position.all();
    },
    position(_, args) {
      return Position.findById(args.id);
    },
  },
  Position: {
    owner(root) {
      return User.findById(root.owner_id);
    },
    favorites(root) {
      return Favorite.getPositionFavorites(root.id);
    },
    views(root) {
      return View.getPositionViews(root.id);
    },
  },
  PositionFilters: {
    countries() {
      return Position.getAllCountries();
    },
    cities(_, args) {
      return Position.getCountryCities(args.country);
    },
    roles() {
      return Position.getAllRoles();
    },
    businessUnit() {
      return Position.getAllBusinessUnit();
    },
    domains() {
      return Position.getAllDomains();
    },
    subDomains(_, args) {
      return Position.getSubDomains(args.domain);
    },
    positions(_, { filters, offset }) {
      return Position.getByFilters(filters, offset);
    },
  },
  Mutation: {
    async closePosition(_, args) {
      return Position.closePosition(args.positionID, args.closedType);
    },
    async createPosition(_, args, context) {
      if (context.user) {
        const position = { ...args.input, owner_id: context.user.id };
        const response = await Position.insert(position);

        return response[0];
      }

      throw new AuthenticationError('You need to be logged');
    },
    async updatePosition(_, args, context) {
      // TODO: Verify if user which is mutating the position is actually the owner of it
      if (context.user) {
        const response = await Position.update(args.input);

        return response[0];
      }

      throw new AuthenticationError('You need to be logged');
    },
  },
};
```

I dont know how is structured because i received got the project now and dont know very much GraphQL.

I have also, `API Context`, in the `FilterResult`, first line.

`Api Context`:

```js
import React from 'react';

const SearchContext = React.createContext();

export default SearchContext;
```

App.js with `ApolloProvider`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';

import client from './graphql/client';
import PrivateRoute from './components/RouteWrapper/PrivateRoute';
import Dashboard from './pages/dashboard/dashboard';
import Search from './pages/search/Search';
import Login from './pages/login/login';
import MutatePosition, { Edit, New, PositionFetcher, ManagerFetcher } from './pages/mutatePosition/index';
import Position from './pages/vacancy/Vacancy';
import View from './pages/vacancy/View';
import Error404 from './pages/404/404';


import 'carbon-components/css/carbon-components.min.css';
import './assets/CSS/style';
import './assets/CSS/style.css';

const App = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/search" component={Search} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute
            exact
            path="/vacancy/new"
            render={() => <MutatePosition>{props => <New {...props} />}</MutatePosition>}
          />

          <PrivateRoute
            exact
            path="/vacancy/:id/edit"
            render={props => (
              <PositionFetcher id={props.match.params.id}>
                {position => <MutatePosition position={position}>{props => <Edit {...props} />}</MutatePosition>}
              </PositionFetcher>
            )}
          />

          <PrivateRoute
            exact
            path="/vacancy/:id"
            render={props => <View {...props}>{props => <Position {...props} />}</View>}
          />

        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </ApolloProvider>
);

export default App;
```

Someone help-me, please?
Error:[image]

Comment: `GET_POSITIONS_BY_FILTER` query? error in resonse/network tab?

Comment: Did you check to ensure the data is available before attempting to make use of it inside the component?